# No UFO sightings and landings?

Tags: android, xcom-enemy-within

I have satellites in every country. Though when I started, so got a UFO as a tutorial, and within one month I was able to launch a satellite in every country using cheats only. I also had a game save in which I was able to launch SATs in every country by the sixth month without any cheats, but as soon as all countries have SATs, no UFOs are seen or land. After a month, I get a warning to protect my SATs even though all my satellites are up and I sold the UFO computers in the black market. I was unable to move forward, and every month then on, my coucil reports thag all UFOs escaped. I don't know what is wrong, and I have interceptors too. BTW I am playing on android. Please tell me what's wrong, and if you need my saves, you can get them to check what's wrong.

Comment: Maybe you broke it by cheating? :-) Try playing the game normally, and see if it works....

Comment: Yup, I made a mistake every time I cheated I made the total launched SATs to be 0 and so there were no UFO sightings. Is there any way to edit the save data of my game. I know there are some interesting editors, but only for PCs or consoles?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed yourself, cheating interacts with parts that makes progress to the game. In the normal course of events game progresses with satellite numbers in the beginning, and "sadly" covered areas has no direct connection with UFO sightings (except it will appear only in covered areas).

Global coverage with cheating is contraproductive, because when you begin to deal with events, you can save 1 area and consequently cause trust drop in 2 areas. Math is easy, you will eventually loose support from countries in the long run. The effect can be balanced with many civilians saved in terror attack missions, so there will be continent bonus to keep issues down.

I'm sure there are editors for android save games, but Simon W wrote, just play it normal :) It is a strategy game, which will not tutor you for best practices, but you will learn on it the hard way. But tactics work like that.